# Open document in SharePoint 2013 using C# or VB.NET & edit the content & then save it automatically to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Please provide a code example in C# or VB.NET using SharePoint Client Side Object Model or Server side - Microsoft.SharePoint.dll which allows the user to open the document in SharePoint 2013 from a ASP.NET Web Form (C#, VB.NET) & edit the content & then save it automatically to SharePoint 2013 without uploading the document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want the user to open the document for editing content or metadata?

Comment: User should be able to open the document & edit the content & then save it automatically to SharePoint 2013 without uploading the document.

Comment: You could use Office Web Apps Server which is responsible for rendering and editing Office documents in the browser. Server itself is free but all users that will edit documents need Office license. But you probably already have licenses for users when you want to edit documents.

Answer (score 0):

you can use interop class from office, the problem is that the server need those dll's. You can get it from this link: [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)
About the code

```
Application app = new Application();

byte[] wordContent = MethodtoGetStreamFromtheLibrary(); //you can figure it out ;)

var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
var tmpFileStream = File.OpenWrite(tmpFile);
tmpFileStream.Write(wordContent, 0, wordContent.Length);
tmpFileStream.Close();

app.Documents.Open(tmpFile);
```

Good Luck

Comment: OpenXML nuget DocumentFormat.OpenXml can be also used. Pro is, that it does not require to install anything on the server and can be run even in serverless envionmenet.